# Tried to install dev version of r package, corrupted a database?

Tags: r, ggplot2, devtools

I was trying to use geom_sf, so I needed to install the dev version of ggplot2. I attempted to do so using the instructions [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2) which had me use:

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
```

But something went wrong! geom_sf still didn't show up, and now I can't load or unload the active or dev versions of tidyverse or ggplot2. I keep getting the following info about the database being corrupt.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/ggplot2/R/ggplot2.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

What to do? I'd like my tidyverse back, but ultimately I still want to install the dev version of ggplot2 so that I can use geom_sf.

Comment: Did you try restarting R? This can occur when you install while a package being installed is already loaded in the session. So I would restart, try loading packages; if that fails, restart a completely clean session, reinstall, restart again, ... profit.

Comment: Yes, that worked! I'd restarted R Studio but hadn't restarted the R session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting comment to answer:*

Did you try restarting R? This can occur when you install while a package being installed is already loaded in the session. So I would restart, try loading packages; if that fails, restart a completely clean session, reinstall, restart again, ... profit.